# Counting lowest values from multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table and I need to count expiration for a year but I have two columns and I need to count the lowest value from them. What function would help with this. Here is a small Example

```
Name    Expiration date    Break date
Nr.1    31-Aug-2019        28-Feb-2023
Nr 2    18-Oct-2018 
Nr 3    30-Sep-2018        21-Jun-2017
Nr. 4   1-Jan-2018
```

AS you can see there will be here:

```
2017 2018 2019 2020
1    2     1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extra "helper" column which takes the minimum between the expiration date and break date.  (Accounting for the possibility of the Break date being empty)

[image]

Then your equation to find the totals for each year would just be a simple `COUNTIF` on that new column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter version of a formula for the helper column:

```
=YEAR(IF(COUNT(B2:C2)=2,MIN(B2:C2),B2+C2))
```

with the difference that this will return a year (other than `1900`) if there is a blank in the `Expiration date` column that is next to a populated cell in the `Break date` column.

For the actual counts I would choose a technique that has been deemed off topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with no helper column

**Formula:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((($B:$B<$C:$C)+($C:$C=""))*($B:$B<>"")*(YEAR($B:$B)=E$1))+((($C:$C<$B:$B)+($B:$B=""))*($C:$C<>"")*(YEAR($C:$C)=E$1)))
```

**Assumptions:**

- Data in columns A:C, with Expiration Date in B and Break Date in C
- Year (2017,2018,2019,2010) in E1:H1

[image]

The formula can be dragged horizontally from E2 to H2.

**Formula Logic (pseudo-code):**

```
IF(OR(AND(OR(B<C,C=""),B<>"",YEAR(B)=X),AND(OR(C<B,B=""),C<>"",YEAR(C)=X))) THEN TRUE
```

**Alternate Solution Using Table**

Because the headers break the original formula, you'll need to make the column references more specific to where the data actually is. A table is the easiest way to do that.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(((Table1[Expiration Date]<Table1[Break Date])+(Table1[Break Date]=""))*(Table1[Expiration Date]<>"")*(YEAR(Table1[Expiration Date])=$E1))+(((Table1[Break Date]<Table1[Expiration Date])+(Table1[Expiration Date]=""))*(Table1[Break Date]<>"")*(YEAR(Table1[Break Date])=$E1)))
```

Tables don't play nice with formulas dragged horizontally, so I put the years in a column:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

=SUM(IF(YEAR(IF($B$2:$B$5

Note: This is an array formula, you must paste it in the cell, then hit `ctrl+shift+enter` and then you can copy and paste it across your table.

The cell works if your data is in A1:C5 and you have the years you want to test across E1:H10. You could then paste the above formula in E2, and then paste accross your table.

[image: Example of how the data should be set up for the formula to function]

The array formula does the following:

1. The first `IF` statement checks to see which value is lower, ColB or ColC.
2. The embedded `IF` statements then check to make sure the values are not 0. If they are 0 they return the other column, if they are not 0, they return its own non-0 value.
3. The `YEAR` function extracts the year from each date.
4. The last `IF` function preformed (but the first written in the function) tests the year against the cell above the sum. If the year matches, it returns 1, if false, 0
5. The `SUM` statement simply sums all the true values